# Uploading pdf file from my app to Docusign

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusignconnect

How to get API to upload a PDF file from my app (Java language), to the docusign?

I was trying to use the Quickstart files from DocuSign but they have only static and I could not find the way to upload the pdf files from my app.

Answer (score 0):

The file is sent as a base64 encoded string.

All you have to do is encode your file as base64.

If you got the quickstart to to work just fine, then you're 90% of the way. The file that your app is handling should be loaded into memory and then you should do the same code:

```
public static Document createDocument(byte[] data, String documentName, String fileExtention, String documentId) {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
    document.setName(documentName);
    document.setFileExtension(fileExtention);
    document.setDocumentId(documentId);
    return document;
```

Comment: in which file of quickstart should I add this code?

Comment: This code is already in quickstart

Comment: Which code example are you using? the main/first one for embedded signing?